# I need to select an element from the below drop-down menu using nerodia

Tags: python-2.7

I need to select an element from the below drop-down menu.

```
`<select name="project_id" class="small" onchange="document.forms.form_set_project.submit();">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">jumbo fruit 1</option>
    <option value="2">jumbo fruit 2</option>
    <option value="3">jumbo fruit 3</option>
    <option value="4">jumbo fruit 4</option>
    <option value="5">jumbo fruit 5</option>
    <option value="8">jumbo fruit 6</option>
</select>`
```

I have tried using this code,

```
`from nerodia.browser import Browser
a= browser.selects(name="project_id")
    a.option(value="1")`
```

but it returned me with errors. How can I accomplish the same.

Comment: What errors did you get?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
Given i tested this in 3.7, but it should still work.

`from nerodia.browser import Browser
a= browser.selects(id="project_id")
    a.select('1')`